# Merge object with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below you see I have this object called westCountries, and right below you will see that I have a dataframe called countryDf.

```
westCountries = {'West': ['US', 'CA', 'PR']}
```

```
# countryDF

      Country 
0        [US]
1        [PR]
2        [CA]
3        [HK]
```

I am wondering how I can include the westCountries obj into my dataframe in a new column called Location? I have tried merging but that doesn't really do anything because oddly enough I need the value in this column to be the name of my key in my object as seen below. NOTE: This output is only an example, I understand there missing correlations with the data I provided and my desired output.

```
  Country Location
0      US     West
1      CA     West
```

I was thinking of doing a few things such as:

- using .isin() and then working with that dataframe to a few more transformations/computations to populate my dataframe, but this route seems a bit foggy to me.
- using df.loc[...] to compare my dataframe with the values in this list and then I can create my own column with the value of my choice.
- converting my object into a dataframe, and then creating a new column in this temporary dataframe and then merging by country so I can include the locations column into my `countryDF` dataframe.

However, I feel like there might be a more sophisticated solution than all these approaches I listed above. Which is why I'm reaching out for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to remove values from the list
- Use a `list comprehension` to match values with the `westCountries` value list and return the `key`
- For the example, the sample dataframe column values are created as strings and need to be converted to `dict` type with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval  # only for setting up the test dataframe

# setup the test dataframe
data = {'Country': ["['US']", "['PR']", "['CA']", "['HK']"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.Country = df.Country.apply(literal_eval)  # only for the test data

westCountries = {'West': ['US', 'CA', 'PR']}

# remove the values from lists, with explode
df = df.explode('Country')

# create the Loc column using apply
df['Loc'] = df.Country.apply(lambda x: [k if x in v else None for k, v in westCountries.items()][0])

# drop rows with None
df = df.dropna()

# display(df)
  Country   Loc
0      US  West
1      PR  West
2      CA  West
```

### Option 2 (Better):

- In the first option, for every row, `.apply` has to iterate through every `key-value` pair in `westCountries` using `[k if x in v else None for k, v in westCountries.items()]`, which is slow.
- It's better to reshape `westCountries` into a flat `dict` with region for the `value` and `state` as the key, using a `dict comprehension`.
- Use [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the `dict` values into the new column

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval  # only for setting up the test dataframe

# setup the test dataframe
data = {'Country': ["['US']", "['PR']", "['CA']", "['HK']"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.Country = df.Country.apply(literal_eval)  # only for the test data

# remove the values from lists, with explode
df = df.explode('Country')

# given
westCountries = {'West': ['US', 'CA', 'PR'], 'East': ['NY', 'NC']}

# unpack westCountries where all values are keys and key are values
mapped = {x: k for k, v in westCountries.items() for x in v}

# print(mapped)
{'US': 'West', 'CA': 'West', 'PR': 'West', 'NY': 'East', 'NC': 'East'}

# map the dict to the column
df['Loc'] = df.Country.map(mapped)

# dropna
df = df.dropna()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and then explode the df using [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
westCountries = {'West': ['US', 'CA', 'PR']}
west = pd.melt(pd.DataFrame(westCountries), var_name='Loc', value_name='Country')

df.explode('Country').merge(west, on='Country')
  Country   Loc
0      US  West
1      PR  West
2      CA  West
```

#### Details

```
pd.DataFrame(westCountries)

#  West
#0   US
#1   CA
#2   PR

# Now melt the above dataframe
pd.melt(pd.DataFrame(westCountries), var_name='Loc', value_name='Country')

#    Loc Country
#0  West      US
#1  West      CA
#2  West      PR

# Now, merge `df` after exploding with `west` on `Country`
df.explode('Country').merge(west, on='Country') # how = 'left' by default in merge

#  Country   Loc
#0      US  West
#1      PR  West
#2      CA  West
```

#### EDIT:

if you have `westCountries` dict with unequal sizes then try this

```
from itertools import zip_longest

westCountries = {'West': ['US', 'CA', 'PR'], 'East': ['NY', 'NC']}

west = pd.DataFrame(zip_longest(*westCountries.values(),fillvalue = np.nan),
                    columns= westCountries.keys())
west = west.melt(var_name='Loc', value_name='Country').dropna()

df.explode('Country').merge(west, on='Country')
```

Example of the above:

```
df
  Country
0    [US]
1    [PR]
2    [CA]
3    [HK]
4    [NY] #--> added `NY` from `East`.

westCountries = {'West': ['US', 'CA', 'PR'], 'East': ['NY', 'NC']}

west = pd.DataFrame(zip_longest(*westCountries.values(),fillvalue = np.nan),
                    columns= westCountries.keys())
west = west.melt(var_name='Loc', value_name='Country').dropna()
df.explode('Country').merge(west, on='Country')

#  Country   Loc
#0      US  West
#1      PR  West
#2      CA  West
#3      NY  East
```

Answer (score 0):

this is probably not the fastest approach in terms of run time but it works

```
import pandas as pd

westCountries = {'West': ['US', 'CA', 'PR']}
df = pd.DataFrame(["[US]","[PR]", "[CA]", "[HK]"], columns=["Country"])

df = df.assign(Location="")
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if any([True for country in westCountries.get('West') if country in row['Country']]):
    row.Location='West'

west_df = df[df['Location'] != ""]
```